# Delete all not .class files from a jar in Bash

Tags: bash

Hi I have a jar file and I want to delete all files with not .class extension.

I try can do the opposite. How to turn around the select? I am not able to find like **grep -v** on zip command.

```
zip --delete "myJar.jar" \*.class
```

Comment: Maybe this will work: `zip --delete "myJar.jar" -x \*.class`. Take a backup, just in case.

Comment: @harrymc zip error: Invalid command arguments (nothing to select from)
-x is invalid paramter

Comment: It might be easier to unzip, delete and rezip.

Comment: zip --delete "myJar.jar" -@  and then pass parameters from the input/or do/while